# May unobserved variable confound or create open backdoor paths, why didn't controlling for the collider O make bad?

Tags: confounding, dag, backdoor-path, collider

[image]

Is the U, the unobserved creating an open backdoor path or confounding?

[image]

Why condition on the collider Occupation good here?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> the unobserved creating an open backdoor path or confounding?

I think your first example is from "Causal Inference: The Mixed Tape" and is used in a stop and frisk example.  If I recall correctly, the author uses this example to motivate collider bias because stop and frisk data conditions on stopping (M) which is a collider between Minority Status (D) and Suspicion (U, unmeasured). Any attempts to estimate the causal effect of minority status of use of force using stop and drink data are hence biased by the open back door via the conditioning on being stopped.

As for the remaining dag and regression model, I need more context.  At
least the page number where these are found in the book.